# Implementing drawing areas in tabs in JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, tabs, javafx

I would want to add a drawing area to my tabs in JavaFX. I am new to the field, and tried adding a Canvas to each tab I create. However, this does not seem to be working. Relevant code included.

```
@FXML
void fileNewTabHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    ++indexTab;
    Tab tab = new Tab("Untitled " + indexTab);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 285);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    gc.fillRect(250, 856, 50, 60);
    tab.setContent(canvas);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
}
```

Here tabPane and indexTab are defined and work as long as I do not use the canvas. Where am I going wrong. Should I use a different method to implement what I want to?

Comment: So what actually happens? Your rectangle seems to be outside the bounds of your canvas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Sample**

There is no real trick to this, you just set the canvas as the content of the tab.

[image: tab sample]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class TabbedCanvas extends Application {

    private int tabId = 0;
    private double W = 200, H = 150;

    private Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Button newTabButton = new Button("New Tab");
        newTabButton.setOnAction(
                event -> addTab(tabPane)
        );
        newTabButton.fire();

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(newTabButton);
        toolBar.setMinHeight(ToolBar.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        VBox layout = new VBox(toolBar, tabPane);
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addTab(TabPane tabPane) {
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab: " + tabId++);
        tab.setContent(createTabContent());
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
    }

    private Node createTabContent() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W, H);

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(randomColor());
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

        return canvas;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(
                random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256)
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: On a related note, suppose i have two different kinds of tabs, and I want to design them in separate FXML files, how do I later add them to my tabPane?

Comment: Ayush, please ask a new question.